# Is it possible to have ng-repeat use an iterator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, iterator, iteration

I have [a problem](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1157) where it looks like I'm going to need to use a [Two step view](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html).

The problem is basically that it appears I won't be able to use translate in the view in the way that I get the text as I want. I can solve this by using the translate service in my controller and then rendering the text into a view object there.

I'd rather not iterate over the list multiple times. Is there a way I can use an iterator (some way of saying `next()` in an `ng-repeat` statement? so that each time `ng-repeat` gets the next object, I can transform it then?

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="artist in nextArtist() track by artist.name">
```

Comment: There is no such thing at the moment. Why would you have to iterate over the data multiple times? How would an iterator make that any different? What you want is probably not very performant (the view will call your iterator more than once per item). While doing it all the controller ensures that the data transformation happens once and only once (per controller instantiation). I'd move all this logic to a service/factory, so it truly happens only once (b/c service/factory is a singleton).

Comment: @SunilD. because otherwise I'll have to loop over it at least once in the controller/service/whatever, to modify, or create new objects that have all the data I need.

Comment: That doesn't sound like multiple times :)

Comment: @SunilD. and then ng-repeat will do it again

Comment: Oh yeah, that does sound like multiple times :)  Note however, that if you call a function inside an ng-repeat it's likely to be called many times for the same item. That's just how Angular's digest cycle works.

Comment: I wanted to make a plunker to show what I'm talking about, but got side tracked... [Check it out](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVBA51KefLuNj3s76vOa?p=preview). If you want to execute your transform function/code as little as possible, putting it inside the ng-repeat is the wrong way to go :)

Comment: just use a scope variable call nextArtists and assign items to it. angular will automatically update it.